# advice needed with ListVew

Tags: android, listview, onlongclicklistener

My activity has a `ListView` .Now suppose you have a long type variable 'id_item_clicked'. And a variable of `ListView` type i.e. 'list' . Now suppose you long clicked an item in the list view.
 Would  `id_item_clicked  = list.getId();` initialise the id of the item long clicked to the variable id_item_clicked? could someone help me with this? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getId()` will retrieve the ID of the ListView itself, not the view you long pressed on.
[Docs for View.getId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId%28%29)

If you want to get Id of the view you long pressed on I suggest implementing an [`OnItemLongClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html) in your activity and using the ID parameter from that

Answer (score -1):

each item on the list has a position . you can use setOnItemLongClickListener for the listview in order to get which was long pressed.

in any case , for more tips regarding listView , watch this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70